# Why we do not use least squares in logit model?

Tags: regression, logistic, maximum-likelihood, least-squares

I am very wondering why we do not use least squares instead of maximum likelihood?

for example we have 3 choices k= 1, 2 ,3

$minimizing: (e^{\beta_{i} X}/(1+\sum e^{\beta_{i} X})- Y)^{2} $   for i=1,2,3

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is because it is not maximum likelihood estimation, so it is not optimal.  Maximum likelihood solves for $\beta$ that makes the observed data most likely to have been observed.  The likelihood function for Bernoulli random variables ($Y=0,1$) involves exponents in $Y$, not squares.

Comment: so you mean this method is logical but result is not good enough?

Comment: It is not logical given that we have a better estimator, but mainly it's not good enough.